# vb.net array string from DB reader

Tags: vb.net

looking for best method of getting a string of dates from my DB in the format:
`Session("AssignedLeave") =  = "1/2/2015","3/15/2015","12/25/2015",ect...`
I have it started but can't figure out appending to array and doing it inside/outside my loop? I have 23 fields in the DB and my `i=4to27` gets the dates correctly...

```
 ' Fill Sessions with user data from PICKS table of the DB
    objConn = New Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(strConnection)
    objCmd = New Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM ResultsRound4 WHERE FDID = @FDID", objConn)
    objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FDID", Session("FDID"))
    Dim MyLv As Array()
    Try
        objConn.Open()
        objRdr = objCmd.ExecuteReader()
        While objRdr.Read()
            for i As Integer =4 to 27
                Session("AssignedLeave") = objRdr.Item(i)
                response.write(i)
            next
        End While
        objRdr.Close()
        objConn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex)
    Finally
        objConn.Close()
    End Try
```

FINAL FIX was:

```
    Try
        objConn.Open()
        objRdr = objCmd.ExecuteReader()
        Dim sb = new StringBuilder()
        While objRdr.Read()
            for i As Integer = 4 to 27
                If objRdr.Item(i) IsNot DBNull.Value Then
                    sb.Append("""" + objRdr.Item(i).ToShortDateString() + """,")
                End If  
            next
        End While
        sb.Length -= 1 'remove the last comma
        Session("AssignedLeave") = sb.ToString()

        objRdr.Close()
        objConn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex)
    Finally
        objConn.Close()
    End Try
```

Comment: Every field from 4 to 27 are string fields representing dates or datetime fields? And you want them all inserted in the Session element with a double quote around each date and a comma to separate them?

Comment: yes - they are date/time and I don't want the time part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a StringBuilder, append every item in the StringBuilder with the appropriate formatting required and, after the loop, assign the whole string to the session variable

```
   Dim sb = new StringBuilder()
   While objRdr.Read()
        for i As Integer = 4 to 27
            If Not objRdr.IsDBNull(i) Then 
                sb.Append("""" + objRdr(i).ToShortDateString() + """,")
            End If
        next
    End While
    sb.Length -= 1 'remove the last comma
    Session("AssignedLeave") = sb.ToString()
```

Comment: error: System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from string "dd/MM/yyyy" to type 'Integer' is not valid. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ParseDouble(String Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat) at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger(String Value) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger(String Value) at Rounds.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\web\mcfrsitcom0\htdocs\LeavePicks\Rounds.aspx.vb:line 168

Comment: getting closer had to fix `reader(i)` to `objRdr.Item(i)` and now i think a few of the end fields are null?  error:System.MissingMemberException: Public member 'ToShortDateString' on type 'DBNull' not found. at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Symbols.Container.GetMembers(String& MemberName, Boolean ReportErrors) at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack) at Rounds.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:

Comment: Yes, if some fields are null (DBNull.Value) another approach is required. Trying to fix the answer now

Comment: got it working, thanks so much: checked for null fix it!

Answer (score 1):

You could fill a `List(Of string)`, then use `String.Join` to concat them:

```
Dim list = New List(Of String)
If objRdr.Read()
    For i As Int32 = 4 To 27
        list.Add(objRdr.GetString(i))
    Next
End If
Session("AssignedLeave") = String.Join(",", list)
```

However, why do you store `Date` as `String` in your table and why do you store rows as columns?

If they are `Date`s and you want to output them without time use `date.ToString("d")` or `dt.ToShortDateString`, if that is your current culture's date-format. Otherwise you can force it by using: `dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

For example:

```
Dim list = New List(Of String)
If objRdr.Read()
    For i As Int32 = 4 To 27
        list.Add(objRdr.GetDateTime(i).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    Next
End If
```

Comment: I'm getting `Dim list = New List(Of String)` error: `Type 'List' is not defined.`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - where am I storing rows as columns ?

Comment: @BarclayVision: `List(Of String)` is a generic list, it is sitting in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace. What framework are you using? " why do you store rows as columns" meant that you should normalize your table since i assume that a relation table to store these values would be more appropiate. Then the selects are more preformant and easier.

Comment: @BarclayVision: so you want to output dates as strings without time, i have edited my answer.

Comment: thanks @Tim, I went with the string builder - but really appreciate your time and help, This will help in another project I have as well.

Comment: @BarclayVision: as you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.80%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) it is already available in .NET 2. The same applies to `String.Join`, although in .NET 2 you need an array instead. Therefore you can use `list.ToArray` which was also already available in .NET 2. So `Session("AssignedLeave") = String.Join(",", list.ToArray())`